# Get dynamically created File from FEED_URI in scrapy

Tags: python, amazon-s3, scrapy

Since I am using FEED_URI parameters which get replaced with content dynamically, I need to get the filename of the created file from Scrapy framework.

```
def handler(event, context):
    process = CrawlerProcess(settings={
        'FEED_FORMAT': 'csv',
        'FEED_URI': 's3://bucket-name/%(name)s/%(time)s.csv'
    })
    process.crawl(BbSpider)
    process.start()
```

##### My aim is to:

get the filename that BbSpider produced and return it from the handler function.

##### What have I tried?

- I checked logs, I found that it is printing the compiled URI as an INFO log:
  `2021-11-03 15:35:23 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored csv feed (32 items) in: s3://bucket-name/bbspider/2021-11-03T11-35-21.csv`. I got inspiration from this and digged into the source code of [feedexport.py](https://docs.scrapy.org/en/master/_modules/scrapy/extensions/feedexport.html). I see feedexport.FeedExport class has a method `_handle_store_success` which prints this line and it is called from `_close_slot`. Then `self.slots` is having multiple slots which have an attribute called `slot.uri`. This will get me the compiled FEED_URI which I am looking for.

The issue I am getting with this approach is:
**How do I create the FeedExport object of the same CrawlerProcess Object to access its `self.slots`.**

- I explored CrawlerProcess.settings Object (process) in hopes of finding the compiled version of FEED_URI, but I am getting URI which I passed (i.e., `'s3://bucket-name/%(name)s/%(time)s.csv'`).
- I tried multiple CrawlerProcess class' attributes and methods, but I am failing to receive a Crawler or FeedExport Object of `process` object.